# Salesforce after Update Trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, soql

I have created the following after update trigger but I am unable to have it to save, I don't quite undetstand why it does not work

```
trigger Adhoc_Approval_process_trigger on Ad_Hoc_Approval__c (after update) {

    list<Ad_Hoc_Approval__c> ladh= new list<Ad_Hoc_Approval__c>(); 
    list<Ad_Hoc_Approval__c> query=[select Status__c,Submitted_for_Approval_Date__c from Ad_Hoc_Approval__c];
    for(Ad_Hoc_Approval__c adh : query)
    {
        if(adh.Status__c =='Submitted for Approval')
        {
            adh.Submitted_for_Approval_Date__c=Date.today();
            ladh.add(adh);
        }

    }

    update ladh;

}
```

I have also converted it to a before update trigger, and it's working fine, can anyone please help me understand why,

```
trigger Adhoc_Approval_process_trigger on Ad_Hoc_Approval__c (before update) {

        for(Ad_Hoc_Approval__c adh : trigger.new)
        {
            if(adh.Status__c =='Submitted for Approval')
            {
                adh.Submitted_for_Approval_Date__c=Date.today();

            }

        }



    }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean fails to save as it doesn't compile? Hm, looks good at a glance, got any errors?

Your 1st version would end up being a neverending loop :) update -> update -> update... Not to mention the query doesn't have any WHERE clause so it would eventually explode anyway once you reach 10,0001 records...

2nd version is much better :) Works only on current trigger's scope and "before update" you get the save to database for free.

Comment: Thanks for your response, correct me if I'm wrong you cannot use an update DML in an after trigger for the same object, however if the DML update other objects, we should be good, correct ?

Comment: Normally you can't you'll get the "UNABLE TO LOCK ROW" error. There's a trick if you really really need it but then it's your job to ensure it won't enter infinite loop & eventually be terminated because of governor limits violations. But you're free to insert, update, delete any other objects that aren't in scope of `trigger.new`.